# How to implement push from apigee in android app

Tags: push-notification, push, apigee

Devices are showing in monitoring.
But how can i send notification from apigee to android devices.
I am very new to this.so
Please help me in brief.

Comment: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/push-notifications-overview

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/push-notifications-overview

It has an overview of how Push notifications work.

In general, this is the workflow:

1. Create an account at Apigee
2. Create an account w/ google and get a dev key
3. Log into Apigee and go to the Admin Portal
4. Create a new "Notifier" using your dev key
5. Download the sample app
6. Run it on a device (Push WILL NOT WORK IN THE SIMULATOR)
7. Go back to the Admin Portal at Apigee and create a Notification (this is what is sent to the phone) using the Notifier you have already created.